# View a Class from the Unity API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am rendering my camera to a cubemap using

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Camera> ().RenderToCubemap (cm);
```

I want view the code for RenderToCubemap(), so I can understand how it works.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Source Code of the Unity3D API is closed. If you want to look at it you'll have to pay for the professional license you then get the source code.

Comment: Not only do you need the professional licence, but source code access is an additional fee on top of the professional licence.

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple and legal way to look at the code. You could decompose it but you will get assembly code not C#.

**Note that reverse engineering is illegal based on the EULA.**

This is what Unity sells, like CocaCola is not giving away the Coke recipe.

But keep in mind that what happens in Camera class is likely to be a code version of basic well known equations from OpenGL. So even though you would not get a one-to-one, OpenGL is probably fairly close.

Comment: There is a simple legal way to look at the code, pay for it. Unity is one of the few commercial companies that offer a special paid licence to access the source of the program. (However it is likely going to cost somewhere in the $10,000-$100,000 price range to get that licence.)

Comment: I can't say 100% but I think you have to be some kind of recognised studio. All in all, I don't think the OP wants to put 10 to 100k just to see the content of one camera method (or is he Martin Skreli?).

Comment: I don't think you need to be a recognized studio, just have the deep enough pockets. "True Studios" will likely have a Enterprise Licence, which does include the source by default, Inde and startups would use the Professional licence which just states that you can get the soruce but you have to talk to a sales person first to negotiate the price. But yea, paying 10K to see one method is not a smart choce.

Comment: or, you could ask some graphics plumber from unity if they can give more info on that method..